# How do I get the class this inside an event function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I create a web worker as follows:

```
export class WorkerApi {

    private worker:Worker;

    constructor() {
        this.worker = new Worker("web-worker.js");
        this.worker.onmessage = this.messageHandler;
    }

    private messageHandler (e) {

        // need "this" for the instantiated WorkerApi object here

        // ...
    }
```

The problem I have is when `messageHandler` is called, `this` is the Worker object. I need access to my `WorkerApi` object. How do I get that? (I'm using TypeScript but I believe this is a JavaScript question.)

Comment: Yeah this isn't JavaScript unless you're using ECMAScript6 and which is still a wee bit different

Comment: @phylax I guess it's TypeScript.

Comment: Ok just read on TypeScript never heard of it and found it it's basically a compiler no?

Comment: Yes, as I put in the question I am using typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

`this.worker.onmessage = this.messageHandler.bind(this);`

The `this` value within the handler will point to your `WorkerApi` instance.

Comment: I gave you an upvote to make up for whoever's downvote.